# URLConnection - send parameter

Tags: java, rest, urlconnection

How to add parameter to my object of type URLConnection?

I have tried addRequestProperty("access_key,"dsd97sd863hb8323hjhd933ok4") and
setRequestProperty("access_key,"dsd97sd863hb8323hjhd933ok4") but with no success.

With postman adding access_key and value in Params works fine.

Comment: What to you mean "parameter"? HTTP requests have headers, bodies, and **query parameters**, each are ways to pass data to an endpoint. It is unclear which your API is accepting. Note: You can make Postman **generate** Java code for the same request

Comment: I mean how to set query parameters to the URLConnection object.

Comment: You just put them in the URL ... `http://some.api.com?access_key=" + accessKey` However, that isn't secure, so unsure why you'd do that

Comment: Yes, I solved it that way. Just trying to figure out is it possible to pass q param with some method. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want `URIBuilder` in Apache HTTPClient 5.x that has `addParameter`. Retrofit might have something as well. Don't think `URLConnection` has anything similar

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer. Appreciate your help! I will investigate URIBuilder most likely.